# How do I instantiate an GPU-enabled virtual machine on Azure

Tags: azure, gpu

I would like to create one or more GPU-enabled virtual machines on Azure. I know that the family is called N-family Virtual Machine, but I cannot choose this type of virtual machine when trying to create one for myself?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a product offering / availability question.

Comment: @DavidMakogon If you can advise me where can I ask this or a better way to ask this it would be more helpful ..

Answer (score 3):

According to this link: [Azure N series release date](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/74f9c2d7-271f-4fff-a748-253cde7e08c2/azure-n-series-release-date?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows) as of March 23, the preview is looking to be in the May 2016 timeframe with GA later in the year.